# Checking types of macro parameters at compile time

Tags: c

To check that two variables have the same structure type I use a macro

```
#define assert_same_struct_types(a, b)    ((void) (sizeof((a)=(b))))
```

If some function-like macro

```
#define m(a,b) blablabla
```

assumes a and b should be of the same structure type, I add a compile time check:

```
#define m(a,b) (assert_same_struct_types(a, b), blablabla)
```

which provokes compiler error if caller of m(a,b) accidentally passes to m different types of structs.

However, this approach doesn't always work for builtin and pointer types due to implicit conversions between them.

So, is it possible to solve this problem for arbitrary types, not necessarily structs?

I need a solution for C89, however, it would be interesting to hear about C99 or C11 possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define ASSERT_SAME_TYPE(a, b)  ((void) (&(a) == &(b)))
```

will get you a compile diagnostic and an error with `-Werror` (for `gcc` or a similar option for other compilers).

Note that a lot of compilers have a non standard extension [`typeof`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) operator to get the type of an object and this can be used to check two types are the same.

Comment: The macro you give seems to be [failing](http://ideone.com/GTZwH) even when I specify same type.

Comment: I follow the conventions of the OP: you have to pass objects and not types as arguments to the macro.

Comment: @ouah: my gcc is silent with -Wall, so it would be nice to eleborate your answer

Comment: The diagnostic is required by the compiler. You can try with `-pedantic` but  with my `gcc` version just having `-Wall` is sufficient  to get the warning.

Comment: @ouah: may be you forgot sizeof ? (it makes expression unevaluated)

Comment: I don't need the no-evaluation as there is no side-effect in this expression (contrary to the one in your question). It works on my side, what test case are you trying?

Comment: @ouah: +1. Sorry, I initially misunderstood your answer.. indeed, almost any compiler should at least warn. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this answer is it fails with literals, and you don't always know ahead of time which args will be constants. eg `&(1)`

Comment: @ideasman42 I don't know any better solution for c89 (without extensions). If the questions allowed `gcc` extensions, a simple solution that also allows literals is the following: `#define ASSERT_SAME_TYPE(a, b) _Static_assert(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b)), "uncompatible types")`. With this macro, `ASSERT_SAME_TYPE(0, 0U);` would fail as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This questions asks about a C89 solution, so far I didn't find a good way to do this, so instead of relying on C89, you can check if the compiler supports `typeof` and use it when available. Its not ideal but means as long as some developers use GCC/Clang/IntelC, the error gets caught. *of course, if you tell your compiler only to support C89 this isn't going to help.*

It gives better type checking but obviously fails to be of any use at all when not supported.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define CHECK_TYPE(var, type)  {  \
    typeof(var) *__tmp;           \
    __tmp = (type *)NULL;         \
    (void)__tmp;                  \
} (void)0

#define CHECK_TYPE_PAIR(var_a, var_b)  {  \
    typeof(var_a) *__tmp;                 \
    __tmp = (typeof(var_b) *)NULL;        \
    (void)__tmp;                          \
} (void)0

#define CHECK_TYPE_PAIR_INLINE(var_a, var_b)  ((void)({  \
    typeof(var_a) *__tmp;                                \
    __tmp = (typeof(var_b) *)NULL;                       \
    (void)__tmp;                                         \
}))

#else
#  define CHECK_TYPE(var, type)
#  define CHECK_TYPE_PAIR(var_a, var_b)
#  define CHECK_TYPE_PAIR_INLINE(var_a, var_b) (void)0
#endif

/* inline type checking - can mix in with other macros more easily using the comma operator,
 * C11 gives best results here */
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L)
#  define CHECK_TYPE_INLINE(val, type) \
    (void)((void)(((type)0) != (0 ? (val) : ((type)0))), \
           _Generic((val), type: 0, const type: 0))
#else
#  define CHECK_TYPE_INLINE(val, type) \
    ((void)(((type)0) != (0 ? (val) : ((type)0))))
#endif
```